# panda data frame applying multiple columns

Tags: python, dataframe, function, dictionary, apply

```
product_code   order    eachprice  
TN45           10        500
BY11           20        360
AJ21           5         800
```

and i need to create a new column based on order and each price if order>=10, then 5% discount, order>=50 then 10% discount for the price, how can i apply a function to achieve this:

```
product_code  order   each_price   discounted_price
TN45          10       500          4500
BY11          20       360          6480
AJ21          5        800          4000
```

i tried to apply a function e.g.
df['discount'] = df.apply(function, axis=1)

but errors prompts
"A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead"

can anyone help? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use nested [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) calls to achieve this. I've added an extra intermediate column to the results for the percentage discount, then used this column to calculate the final discounted price:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'product_code': ['TN45', 'BY11', 'AJ21'],
    'order': [10, 20, 5],
    'each_price': [500, 360, 800]
})

df['discount'] = np.where(
    df['order'] >= 50,
    0.1,
    np.where(
        df['order'] >= 10,
        0.05,
        0
    )
)

df['discounted_price'] = df['order'] * df['each_price'] * (1 - df['discount'])
```

Note that my results are slightly different from those in your expected output, but I believe they are correct based on the description of the discount conditions you gave:

```
  product_code  order  each_price  discount  discounted_price
0         TN45     10        500      0.05            4750.0
1         BY11     20        360      0.05            6840.0
2         AJ21      5        800      0.00            4000.0
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mention you are trying by using apply function. I did the same and is working. I am not sure what part of the function was wrong in your case.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
     'product_code': ['TN45', 'BY11', 'AJ21'],
     'order': [10, 20, 5],
     'each_price': [500, 360, 800]
})

# This is the apply function
def make_discount(row):
     total=row["order"] * row['each_price']
     if row["order"] >= 10:
         total=total - (total*0.05)
     elif row["order"] >= 50:
         total=total - (total*0.1)
     return total
```

##### Output:

```
df["discount_price"] = df.apply(make_discount, axis=1)
df
  product_code  order  each_price  discount_price
0         TN45     10         500          4750.0
1         BY11     20         360          6840.0
2         AJ21      5         800          4000.0
```

Comment: hi Coldy, thanks ,  but still have warning message:  df1['discounted'] = df1.apply(make_discount, axis=1)
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: There is a useful link on its understanding https://stackoverflow.com/a/53954986/3414466 which could help that to be solved. However, it is a warning which could be ignored as well sometimes. If you think the answer has helped you could accept it.